# Nobody is answering my question

Tags: discussion

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/135609?noredirect=1

The link above is my question. I asked a question, displayed my effort and asked for an explanation to my queries regarding naming aromatic compounds.

I received no good answer. A person tried to explain in the comments but I could not understand him and I asked him to answer with an explanation, but he did not answer. What should I do?

Comment: We are all volunteers here, if no-one finds the time to answer your question, then unfortunately it will remain unanswered.

Comment: Your question is rather blatantly too broad. Just read some textbook highlighting organic nomenclature. You didn't even know that both names are valid synonyms and perhaps still imagine there still like one *true* name.

Comment: The link in this question is dead.

Answer (score 4):

First, see Help Center: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) and familiarize yourself with [the bounty system](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).
Of course, in order to take advantage of it, you first have to gain some reputation points by contributing to the site.

Also, there is [a nice answer by Tim Post on Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251430/7589898) who summarized plenty of useful suggestions for struggling users like you:

> Bounties are a great way to accomplish this, I've also found the following useful:
>
> - Sharing a link to my question on Twitter (might be more useful to some than others)
> - *Politely* asking folks in a chat room related to what you're working with if they know the answer to your question
> - Linking to the question in other places you're communicating with other programmers about your problem
> - Blogging about the problem and linking to the question

Comment: In view of your reputation and knowledge, why don't you answer my question?

Comment: Why should I and how is this relevant to your question here on Meta?

Comment: I think this site is for helping people understand things they do not understand. In the case of relevancy, nobody is answering my question, so at least you can do it to support the reason the site is in existence. By the way, no need to be so angry. I just asked you to answer. Sir.

Comment: See, the participation is voluntarily, and users contribute to the topics they are interested in. Your question here was "What should I do?", and I already answered it, but it doesn't seem like it had any effect as you keep on suggesting me (again, why?) to post an answer, which I respectfully decline.